# What is the name for this type of chain?

Tags: jewelry, material-identification

I am making a necklace with a bunch of chains. I found a picture of a type of chain that I want to buy (on Etsy or at a craft store), but I don't know what to ask/search for. I would describe the chain as kind of a flat mesh look, like alternating bricks.

Here are the pictures: I am looking for the tiny gold chain that appears a few times in this larger necklace in the first picture (it's four bricks 'tall', you really have to zoom in - sorry I wish there was a way I could circle it), but I've added two other pictures with similar chains to better see what it looks like.

[image: picture 1] [image: picture 2] [image: picture 3]

<sup>(Click to see larger images)</sup>

Comment: Why don't you show the picture at the shop? Maybe they do not know the name either.

Comment: Hi Sarah, welcome to Arts & Crafts! Unfortunately, this question doesn't seem right for this website. You want to buy an item but want us to identify the technical name - there is neither art or craft involved.

Comment: @Joachim I want a certain type of chain to add to a jewelry piece I'm working on. I don't know what this type of chain is called therefore I can't find the piece. Your comment doesn't make sense to me. I asked the question to help finish a craft project I'm working on... if you have a suggestion for a better way to phrase my question I am open to it.

Comment: @virolino thanks for your suggestion. I haven't been to every craft store in my area (who has that kinda time) but no one at my local JoAnns seems to know.

Comment: What type of metal is it? Silver?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am in no way a jewelry maker, or jewelry specialist. Mostly good at looking up information. Since art is in my field(of enjoyment), spent some time researching the types of chain that was described above.

It seems like the type of chain you are looking for is called, "panther chain."
[image]

Comment: ahh the panther chain!! I bow to your research prowess! My eyes were bleeding from all the chain comparison photos on google. This indeed looks like exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your time! Sorry I don’t have reputation to upvote your answer.

Comment: Yes, it is a panther link chain.